# sed command not select values

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed

I need help for sed command.
I want to select json values and assign to variables by selecting with sed.
How can I do it?

i.e.

```
echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | sed ?
url=news.google.com
int=3
```

Comment: avoid using `sed` for json input... use parsers like `jq` or a programming language with json modules..

Comment: Is this really typical of the lines you want to scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`, though `grep` is not right tool to parse json, for given data this should work

```
grep -oP 'url:\K[^,}]*'
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | grep -oP 'url:\K[^,}]*' 
news.google.com

$ echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | grep -oP 'int:\K[^,}]*' 
3
```

- `\K` is used for reseting the previously matched data

to save in variable, wrap above one inside `$(...)` like

```
url=$( echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | grep -oP 'url:\K[^,}]*' )
```

**OR**

```
$ url=$( grep -oP 'url:\K[^,}]*' <<<"{url:news.google.com,int:3}" )
$ echo $url
news.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following `sed` and let us know if this helps you:

```
url=$(echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | sed 's/\({\)\([^:]*\)\(:\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\4/')
echo "$url"
news.google.com


int=$(echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | sed 's/.*://;s/}//')
echo "$int"
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` only for the most simple JSON structures over which you have complete control. If it becomes anything nested, `sed` is *not* the tool that you want. As Sundeep said, `jq`, Perl, Python and the likes are a far better choice.

That being said,

```
echo "{url:news.google.com,int:3}" | sed 's/{//;s/}//;s/:/=/g;s/,/\n/g'
```

will produce your output.